# Implementing Triplet Loss inside Keras Layers

Tags: python-3.x, keras, keras-layer

In this blog [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/lossless-triplet-loss-7e932f990b24), he implements the triple loss outside the Kears layers. He gets the `anchor_out`, `pos_out` and `neg_out` from the network and then passes them to the `triplet_loss()` function he defined.

I wonder if I can calculate the triplet_loss within the Keras layers by defining my own `Lambda` layers.

Here's my network design:

```
margin=1

anchor_input = Input((600, ), name='anchor')
positive_input = Input((600, ), name='positive_input')
negative_input = Input((600, ), name='negative_input')

# Shared embedding layer for positive and negative items
Shared_DNN = Dense(300)

encoded_anchor = Shared_DNN(anchor_input)
encoded_positive = Shared_DNN(positive_input)
encoded_negative = Shared_DNN(negative_input)

DAP = Lambda(lambda tensors:K.sum(K.square(tensors[0] - tensors[1]),axis=1,keepdims=True),name='DAP_loss') #Distance for Anchor-Positive pair
DAN = Lambda(lambda tensors:K.sum(K.square(tensors[0] - tensors[1]),axis=1,keepdims=True),name='DAN_loss') #Distance for Anchor-Negative pair
Triplet_loss = Lambda(lambda loss:K.max([(loss[0] - loss[1] + margin),0],axis=0),name='Triplet_loss') #Distance for Anchor-Negative pair

DAP_loss = DAP([encoded_anchor,encoded_positive])
DAN_loss = DAN([encoded_anchor,encoded_negative])

#call this layer on list of two input tensors.

Final_loss = Triplet_loss([DAP_loss,DAN_loss])

model = Model(inputs=[anchor_input,positive_input, negative_input], outputs=Final_loss)
```

However, it gives me the error:

```
Tried to convert 'input' to a tensor and failed. Error: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 0
    From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'Triplet_loss_4/Max/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?,1], []
```

The error is from the `Triplet_loss` layer. In the `K.max()` function, the first number `loss[0] - loss[1] + margin` has the shape `(None,1)`. Yet the second number 0 has the shape `(1)`. The two number are not of the same shape and therefore the `K.max()` function gives out an error.

My problem is, how to solve this error? 
I have tried replacing the `0` with `K.constant(0,shape=(1,))` and `K.constant(0,shape=(None,1))`, but they doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Triplet_loss = Lambda(lambda loss: K.maximum(loss[0] - loss[1] + margin, 0.0),
                      name='Triplet_loss')
```

I think the issue with this line

```
Triplet_loss = Lambda(lambda loss:K.max([(loss[0] - loss[1] + margin), 0], 
                      axis=0),name='Triplet_loss')
```

is that you are putting `loss[0]-loss[1]+margin` tensor and `0` in the list bracket, which keras interprets as concatenating two tensors.  This fails due to the size mismatch; `0` is a scalar and has rank 0, while the first one is 2d array.  This is what the error means.

To compare a tensor against a single value element-wise, use `K.maximum`, which broadcasts automatically when one of the arguments is a scalar.

Comment: Indeed it works! I didn't notice the subtle difference between `K.max()` and `K.maximum()` Thanks for pointing it out.